# How do I make my one file processing.js game into an .exe file?

Tags: javascript, html, processing.js

I am trying to make my Processing.js game (which is in an html file) into an .exe file but I don't understand how.

It works fine when opened in a browser but I want to make it an .exe file for easy opening on a windows computer.

The entire game is just one html file with ~700 lines of code, it's rather simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're barking up the wrong tree. I don't think trying to convert an HTML file into a `.exe` file is going to make it easier for people to run your code.

If I were you, I would find a a web host that will host your HTML file. Here are a few options:

- GitHub Pages
- itch.io
- Game Jolt
- OpenProcessing
- CodePen

All of these are free, and would allow you to send a URL to other people to let them run your code in their browsers.

You could also just send them your `.html` file and have them open that up in their browsers, but unless you have some special reason to do that, I'd stick with the web hosting option.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/html/hosting) is a tutorial on web hosting, and [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) is a tutorial on Processing.js, including places to upload it.